# Ограничение рассылки уведомлений

Tags: python, python-3.x, schedule

У меня есть такая простенькая функция которая каждые 10 секунд получает значение из бд и если это значение удовлетворяет условиям то возвращает его. Все работает хорошо.

```
import pyodbc,datetime,schedule, time

from threading import Thread

def prostoi():
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=DRIVER;SERVER=SERVER;DATABASE=DATABASE;UID=UID;PWD=PWD')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with conn:
        sql = "тут запрос"
        for row in cursor.execute(sql):
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            if (now-row[0]).seconds > 300 and (now-row[0]).days<1:
                pros = now-row[0]
                return result
            else:
                pass
      

def run_schedule_reg():
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(prostoi)
    
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

thread = Thread(target=run_schedule_reg).start()
```

Но появилась необходимость, если это значение , например больше 300, то надо отправить уведомление. Функция для отправки уведомления уже написана и тоже работает. Если я ее буду вызывать место return , то уведомления будут отсылаться каждые 10 секунд. Как мне можно ограничить отсылку этих уведомлений , например чтобы они отсылались раз в 10 минут. Но при это запросы к бд попрежнему выполнялись каждые 10 секунд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай декоратор вроде такого:

```
def ratelimit(limit=600):
    def deco(func):
        func.lastrun = 0
        def inner(*a,**kw):
            if time.time() - func.lastrun > limit:
                func.lastrun = time.time()
                return func(*a,**kw)
        return inner
    return deco
```

Тут навешивается на функцию время её последнего запуска. А использовать так:

```
@ratelimit(600)
def sendmsg(data):
   ....
```

Comment: а потом просто вызывать `sendmsg(result)` в `prostoi` ?

Comment: да, вызываешь sendmsg, а запускается вместо неё inner

Comment: что-то ругается на строчку     `def sendmsg(msg):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Хотя там моя функция и передаю нужное значение туда

Comment: один ретурн забыл

Comment: крутая фишка, эти декораторы, надо больше про них почитать. Спасибо!

Comment: еще вопрос небольшой, использовать вот так декоратор в данном случае лучше чем если бы я допустим объявил глобальную переменную и по сути также в нее записывал последнюю сработку? просто была сразу такая идея

Comment: Можно и так, переменная тоже не плоха, но теряется в коде